# Darken element background on hover

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

I do not want to define a color and style for every button on hover or PointerOver. I want to darken any element by say 20% or I’d be fine with an overlay that is say black with an opacity on it. I’ve looked into VisualStates on a ControlTemplate and also using reveal highlight, reveal focus, and acrylics but have not been able to get this to work. Do UWP not allow for this? I’d be fine having this in XAML or C# code. Can someone point me in the right direction or show an example from their project that does similar to what I’m looking to do? In my code below I have removed the default pointer over visual state because it looks terrible. Thanks.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentPresenter 
                x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Is this Xamarin or UWP???

Comment: It’s a Xamarin UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to darken any element by say 20% or I’d be fine with an overlay that is say black with an opacity on it.

I'm afraid you can't specify style for each element, In general, we need edit  `PointerOver` `VisualState` change the matched part to darken the element, but it can't apply to all the elements, Currently, modify the style to change `PointerOver` state is only way that we can approach.

Answer (score 0):

UWP allows this. However you are not using UWP but rather Xamarin.Forms. UWP is only your compilation target, the user interface capabilities of your Xamarin project are limited by Xamarin.Forms capabilities.

The only way to achieve that in Xamarin.Forms would be to write a custom renderer for UWP.